# How to switch for example QTextEdit.cpp/QTextEdit.h in QtCreator

Tags: qt, qt5, qt-creator

What's my purpose is i want to view **QTextEdit.cpp** file when i am currently in the document named **QTextEdit.h** in **QtCreator 5.8**.

For more details, if i want to view QWidget.cpp, i will do the following steps.

1. Press F2 on **QWidget** which will change my current document to **qwidget.h**.
2. Press F4 because i want to go to the **qwidget.cpp** file. But when i do this, nothing happened.

I want to achieve the goal using F4 to switch between Qt's source file and Qt's header file, not my own files!

To view source code, i have found three ways on Internet.

**1.Go to source code folder, search it using system search tool. I consider it as not convinient.**

**2.Set a debug breakpoint at somewhere such as textEdit.copy(). I consider it as stupid.**

**3.Open qt.pro in $$QT_INSTALL_DIR/5.8/Src. But it throws some errors when i open it. It's not convinient for me to paste these errors here and i also think it's not necessary.**

Are there anyother ways for me to achieve my goals?

Thanks for help.

Comment: Google: qtcreator+hotkeys

Comment: Do you have source code? it looks like you don't have that, install source code first then above will work.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that i have installed source code.

Comment: You need to attach qt project files to your project

Comment: If you mean 'double click' qt.pro file in Src folder, I did do this. It shows me the errors like this 'Cannot read C:/Qt/Qt5.8.0/5.8/build-qt-Desktop_Qt_5_8_0_MinGW_32bit-Debug/qtbase/config.tests/configure.cfg: No such file or directory
Error while parsing file C:\Qt\Qt5.8.0\5.8\Src\qt.pro. Giving up'．If i misunderstand your words, can you tell me your ways step by step?

Answer (score 2):

I will give my own answer.

If someone wants to view **Qt**'s source code, i always insist that it would be better for him to use **Qt Creator** to find it because the IDE can provide the '**switch headers/sources**' function which makes things easier.

To find it , you need to follow the steps below.

1.Using '**Search Results**' tool in **Qt Creator** to find it for example **QTextEdit.cpp**.

2.In **scope** combobox, choose 'Files in File System' option.

3.In **search for** lineEdit, type 'a'. It's for enabling the **search** btn.

4.In **directory** lineEdit, type your source code directory, for me, like '...\Qt5.8.0\5.8\Src'.

5.In **filemode** combobox, type 'QTextEdit.cpp'.

6.Click **search** button.

You will find **QTextEdit.cpp** in search results, you are also able to use '**switch headers/sources**' function.

I have also found a bug.

For me, i have two versions of Qt Creators. One is 5.4.1, another is 5.8.0.

5.4 searches quickly for nearly 1s while 5.8 needs nearly 1m.